# How to reduce the image resolution and memory size when saving or while capturing an image in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

In my **contacts application** i used an image view to display the contact persons image,

in this process while saving the data user can *save the contact person image as well (in the form of string, image file name)*.

I copy the images in sand box (Documents directory) and save the file names of images

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

            NSString *DirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:storedPicsDict.contactImage forKey:@"oldContactPic"];

            //To SET the NEw IMAGE images from directory path
            CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
            CFStringRef generatedUUIDString = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
            CFRelease(uuid);
            NSString* hashKey = [(NSString*)generatedUUIDString autorelease];
            self.ContactImageFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png",DirectoryPath,hashKey];

            storedPicsDict.contactImage = self.ContactImageFilePath;
            [contactPicture setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            isNewContactImage = true;
      }


      [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

the respective save image will displayed in contact's information.

But w**hen i saved few more images more than 6/7 it causes memory warnings and the and app gets crashed/slow down.**

So i need to save images with LOW RESOUTION and LOW MEMORY SIZE,

How is it possilbe, thanks

Answer (score 11):

1>Save the image in jpeg format so that image size gets reduced

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(your_UIImage_to_save, 0.5);
[imgData writeToFile:path_of_doc_dir_with_image_name atomically:YES];
```

2>

If you want to reduce the quality and size of the image you can use this code

```
CGSize newSize=CGSizeMake(50,50); // I am giving resolution 50*50 , you can change your need
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 3):

how about using this

```
UIImage *small = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:original.CGImage scale:0.25     orientation:original.imageOrientation];
```

and save the smaller image to a tmp file path for uploading. Do the images need to be .png?
Otherwise, you may also try  UIImageJPEGRepresentation  to lower the image's quality.